# Calling some required logic in completion closure when self is nil

Tags: swift, automatic-ref-counting

I have such class. I'm trying to implement `execute` method where some executor will do its work and after the work is done the completion closure is running with result as the input. I just want to make sure that this closure will do logging using `logger` and will call `someFunctionToCallAfterExecute`. But because of weak self it can be a condition when `self` is deallocated and this code will not execute. I was trying to use capture list and capture `logger` and reference to the `someFunctionToCallAfterExecute` but when I'm capturing reference to the function then deinit is not calling. No problem with `logger` alone in capture list but then I don't have reference to the function. Using unowned self will crash the application. Where is the best place to put logic `someFunctionToCallAfterExecute` so there will be no retain cycle to self? What are best practices to make sure that some code will execute in closure even if self is nil?

```
class TaskImpl: Task {

    let executor: TaskExecutor
    let logger: Logger

    init(executor: TaskExecutor, logger: Logger) {
        self.executor = executor
        self.logger = logger
    }

    func execute(completion: @escaping (ExecutionResult) -> Void) {
        executor.run { [weak self] result in
            // This is required to be logged always after execution even self is nil
            self?.logger.log(msg: "Task done")
            // This method is required to be called always even when self is nil
            self?.someFunctionToCallAfterExecute(result)
            completion(result)
        }
    }

    func someFunctionToCallAfterExecute(result: ExecutionResult) {
        // do something with result
    }

    deinit {
        print("- task deinit")
    }
}
```

Comment: If `someFunctionToCallAfterExecute` can be `static`, that would solve your problem.  Of course then you can’t access any of `TaskImpl` instance properties

Comment: Also, if you can guarantee the closure is called and then disposed of, then you can capture by strong reference

Comment: On the surface, it looks like you could make `executor` optional, capture `self` as a strong reference.  After running the closure, if `isKnownUniquelyReferenced` returns `true` set `executor` to `nil`